# ignore string variables in regex

Tags: regex, python-2.7

If, for example, there is a video website which has a search option.

http://example.com/search=query

and it return all the search results in that form:

```
<a href="LinkToVideo"</a><img src="ImageSource" alt="AltDescription"><b>VideoName</b>
```

I want to use this data, so i send a request to the website, and then use `re` to return a list with `LinkToVideo`, `ImageSource`, `AltDescription` and `VideoName`:

```
response = urllib2.urlopen("http://example.com/search=" + query)
resp = response.read()
search_list = re.compile('<a href="(.+?)"</a><img src="(.+?)" alt="(.+?)"><b>(.+?)</b>').findall(resp)
return search_list
```

and it return a list like this:

`[('example.com/video1.mp4', 'example.com/image1.jpg', 'blah blah ', 'Cats'),('example.com/video2.mp4', 'example.com/image2.jpg', 'blah', 'Dogs'),('example.com/video3.mp4', 'example.com/image3.jpg', 'blah blah blah', 'Zebra')]`

The problem is that i **dont** need the alt description, but it changes.

I want that list will look like this:

`[('example.com/video1.mp4', 'example.com/image1.jpg', 'Cats'),
('example.com/video2.mp4', 'example.com/image2.jpg', 'Dogs'),
('example.com/video3.mp4', 'example.com/image3.jpg','Zebra')]`

I know i can ignore this, but it the real site (this is just an example) the list is much bigger and there is more data i need to ignore.

I searched google and didnt find a solution. Im sorry if the title isnt describe the problem exactly.

**Thanks**

Answer (score 2):

Use a non-capturing group (`(?:…)`) like this:

```
'<a href="(.+?)"</a><img src="(.+?)" alt="(?:.+?)"><b>(.+?)</b>'
```

Or just get rid of the group entirely:

```
'<a href="(.+?)"</a><img src="(.+?)" alt=".+?"><b>(.+?)</b>'
```

I should also point out that using regular expressions to parse arbitrary HTML is a pretty bad idea and has been known to [cause madness](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1715579). I'd strongly recommend using a proper [html parser](https://docs.python.org/2/library/htmlparser.html) instead.